# Dynamically changing content of modal on list element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html page that is simulating the newsfeed of a social network website. here, posts from different users are generated as li on an un-ordered list. I want to show a pop up modal on the click even of any of these list elements that would dynamically show the content of that particular list element. the mark up is like below:

```
<body>  
    <div class="container" >


        <ul id="newsfeed">
            <li class="news" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

                <img src="someimage_1.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="60" height="60">
                <p class="title">jhon</p>
                <p class="text">good moprning every body</p>
                <p>posted at 12:30pm</p>

                <hr>

            </li>

            <li class="news" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

                <img src="someimage_1.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="60" height="60">
                <p class="title">jimmy</p>
                <p class="text">hello every body</p>
                <p>posted at 12:30pm</p>

                <hr>

            </li>

            <li class="news" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

                <img src="someimage_1.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="60" height="60">
                <p class="title">joe</p>
                <p class="text">felling bored at home</p>
                <p>posted at 12:30pm</p>

                <hr>

            </li>

        </ul>


        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="popup">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

The JQuery i have tried:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var element = $(event.relatedTarget); // the li that triggered the modal to show
        var dynamic_text = element.find('.text').val(); // Extract the value of the .text div inside that li
        var modal = $(this);
        $("#popup").html('the users post says: ' + dynamic_text);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your content is in #popup not .popup, try $('#popup').html('the users post says: ' + dynamic_text));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.popup` is the class, not the id. Need to Change

```
  modal.find('.popup').text('the users post says: ' + dynamic_text);
```

to

```
  $("#popup").html('the users post says: ' + dynamic_text);
```

and change val to text this:

```
 var dynamic_text = element.find('.text').text();
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6oh9aacL/1/

Comment: i tried, but still it shows the default text on the modals body

Comment: Thanks, but this is a bit strange though. the code works in fiddle but is not working in my browser when i try to do it from html flie.

Comment: Try debugging from the console.

Comment: found the problem. In the head i was loading one version of jquery with bootstraps minified js and in the body i loading some version of jquery again. that was causing the problem